# View responsibilities in MVC patten in Java

Tags: java, model-view-controller, input, view

This is my first time using MVC pattern (no GUI) and i have a little bit of confusion in my head. I am realizing a Menu.

1. Can the view ask to other classes, for example an InputData class with only static methods, to receive user's input and print some messages of errors regarding the input? (look at CASE 1) Or it is controller's job to recive input from the user? (look at CASE 2) Or maybe it is Main class's job?
2. Which code is better between:

controller

```
    logInModel.logIn();
    if(logInModel.getBool()) {
        //do something
    } else{
        //do something
    }
```

LogInModel

```
private final String password = "abc"
private boolean logInSuccess = false;

public void logIn(String s) {
    if(s.equals("abc")) logInSuccess = true;
} 

public boolean getBool {
    return logInSuccess;
}
```

or

controller

```
    if(logInModel.logIn()) {
        //do something
    } else{
        //do something
    }
```

LogInModel

```
private final String password = "abc"

public boolean logIn(String s) {
    return s.equals("abc") ? true : false;
}
```

CASE 1

Controller

```
int intValue = view.askNumericInput(str);
```

View

```
public int askNumericInput(String str) {
    return InputData.readInteg(str);
}
```

Here the View is asking to the InputData class to take user's input and check it. I do not know if this is allowed in the MVC pattern.

InputData

```
  public static int readInteg(String str)
  {
   boolean end = false;
   int value = 0;
   Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
   do
    {
     System.out.print(str);
     try
      {
       value = sc.nextInt();
       end = true;
      }
     catch (InputMismatchException e)
      {
       System.out.println(/*message*/);
      }
    } while (!end);
   return value;
  }
```

CASE 2

Controller

```
            try {
                int i = InputData.readInteg();
            } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
                view.printSomething(InputData.getMsg());
            }
```

View

```
public int printSomething(String s) {
    System.out.println(s);
}
```

InputData

```
public int readInteg() {
      Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
      int value = 0;
      value = sc.nextInt();
      return valoreLetto;
}

public String getMsg() {
    return ERROR_MSG;
}
```

I'm confused.

Comment: Anyone who can help me?

Comment: What do you mean with `ask to other classes`?

Comment: I mean, a View method call an InputData method to do the job. i edited my question.

Comment: Edited again. Thank you.